# amazon instant video release date not accurate

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been trying to get release dates for Amazon Instant Videos and noticed that the release date field is not accurate.

E.g. For this movie here: [http://www.amazon.com/Conan-The-Barbarian/dp/B006ANJ4BW/ref=sr_1_2?s=instant-video&ie=UTF8&qid=1378711982&sr=1-2&keywords=Conan+the+Barbarian](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006ANJ4BW)

The release year listed on the page is 2011. However when I use the ItemLookup API here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html I'm getting the following as release date, which is far from accurate: "2013-07-09"

I'm not finding any information about this on Amazon's developer forum. I'm wondering if anyone knows whether this is a real issue, or how to report such issues to Amazon

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same problem. Not sure what the deal is with this, and we've tried other search items, but no luck. Instead we tried our hand with a plex/jquery hack and that worked. Will try to re-find the link, but that solved it for us.

Comment: Interested to know your plex/jquery hack :)